# Estimation Error Calculation

Tags: variance, optimization, monte-carlo, estimators

I'm learning about variance reduction for Monte Carlo methods and I am confused about how to calculate the "estimation error" of a given method.

My question is how should I interpret "Estimation Error" given the context below?

In my textbook, there is the following setup:

We have a Random Variable ${X}$ with a given distribution. Our goal is to approximate ${E[h(X)]}$ via Monte-Carlo and calculate the "Estimation Error" of our estimate.

**First Approach**

Using Simple Random Sample (naive) Monte Carlo, we draw a simple random sample of size ${N}$ from the target distribution of ${X}$ (in the textbook example this is a normal distribution and we use an R function to get the random draws). We then approximate ${E[h(X)]}$ via ${\Sigma_i \frac{h(X_i)}{N}}$.

Then the textbook gives the "Estimation Error" as ${\sqrt{\frac{s^2(h(\dot{X}))}{N}}}$, where ${\dot{X}}$ is the vector of sample points and ${s^2(*)}$ is the sample variance function.

To me this makes sense. Because we are sampling directly from the distribution of ${X}$, variation within a sample will be the same as the variation across samples. So, ${\hat{Var}(\hat{E}[h(X)])}$ can be approximated with just one sample.

**Second Approach (Stratified Sampling)**

In place of Simple Random Sampling, we now divide the distribution of ${X}$ into ${N}$ strata and take a single sample point ${X_i}$ from each stratum. The sample points are chosen uniformly within the limits of each stratum. (For example if the target distribution was uniform between 0 and 10 and we divided the space into 5 strata, then the second sample point would be taken uniformly between 2 and 4. these are sampled uniformly between the limits of the stratum). The strata are chosen by evenly dividing the interval ${(0,1)}$ into ${N}$ segments, then computing ${F^{-1}(p_i)}$ where ${p_i}$ are the end points of the ${N}$ segments. This makes ${P(X_i \epsilon A_i)}$ equal to ${1/N}$ for each strata ${A_i}$

The textbook says to use the same formula from the first approach for both the estimator of ${E[h(X)]}$ and the "estimation error" of the second approach.

To me it makes sense that, under stratified sampling, ${\hat{E}[h(X)]}$ is still ${\Sigma_i \frac{h(X_i)}{N}}$. This is because we've chosen the strata in such a way that ${P(X_i\epsilon A_i) = \frac{1}{N}}$ and we only have a single sample point from each stratum.

However, using the same "estimation error" calculation doesn't make sense to me. The variance within a particular stratified sample (one run of the experiment), ${s^2(h(\dot{X}))}$ must be quite a bit wider than the variance across multiple samples, ${s^2(\hat{E}[h(X)])}$ because stratification ensures our samples spread the whole distribution each time; So ${h(\dot{X})}$ will be very wide in a single sample. However, ${\dot{X}}$ won't jiggle around much across samples so we will get very nearly the same value for ${\hat{E}[h(X)]}$ in each run of the experiment (i.e. the "estimation error" doesn't seem to capture the variation of the estimator).

Is the book misusing "estimation error", or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems indeed most bizarre to suggest using the stratified sample in the standard deviation as if nothing changed from iid sampling circumstances...

Comment: Could you please provide the reference of the textbook and/or a screenshot of the quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The mean of the stratified estimator is
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_i \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i \int_{A_i}h(x_i)Nf(x_i)\text dx_i=\int_{\cup_iA_i}h(x)f(x)\text dx=\mathbb{E}[h(X)]$$
The variance of the stratified estimator is
$$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_i \text{var}[h(X_i)]$$
and also
$$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_i \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)^2] 
+ \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i\ne j} \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)]\mathbb{E}[h(X_j)]
-\frac{1}{N} \mathbb{E}[h(X)]^2\\
=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_i \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)^2] + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i} \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)] \mathbb{E}[h(X)]\\
- \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i} \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)]^2 -\frac{1}{N} \mathbb{E}[h(X)]^2\\
=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_i \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)^2] + \frac{N-1}{N}\mathbb{E}[h(X)]^2- \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i} \mathbb{E}[h(X_i)]^2
$$
While the first term can be (unbiasedly) estimated by a single stratified sample, both other terms require **two** single stratified samples to produce an unbiased estimate, as requested in the above 1973 JASA paper. *(If the strata are regular enough to enjoy symmetry a second sample could be deduced from the first one by applying this (or these) symmetry move(s) but I am unsure a reliable variance could be deduced because of the symmetry and hence dependence between both samples.)*

Comment: This makes sense to me. I wondered if maybe they were meaning that the estimate of the population variance also converges or something like that. I think it is probably an error though.